# Predefine before and after for CSS

Tags: css

The following code doesn't work. I want to predefine the `:before` and `:after` to be used in everywhere in the code.

```
&:after, &:before{
content:""; display:block; width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:50%;
}
.myclass:after{background-color:red;}
```

But the following code works:

```
    .myclass:after{background-color:red;
    content:""; display:block; width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:50%;
}
```

What am I doing wrong in defining it?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Does `&` mean `*`? Or are you trying to only set the defaults for styles that have a `:before` or `:after` defined? If it's the latter, you will need to use a CSS preprocessor, because it isn't part of the language.

Comment: I am trying to only set the defaults for styles that have a `:before` or `:after` defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` not(&) is the selector for "all"

```
*::after, *::before{
    content:""; 
    display:block; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

`&` is used in SASS (and probably other pre-processors) to attach selectors like:

```
.test {
   &::after, &::before { // renders to .test::after, .test::before
        content:""; 
        display:block; 
        width:100%; 
        height:100%; 
        border-radius:50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I dont want to use saas or any preprocessor. i just want to use css, after applying `*::after, *::before{` nothing is showing on the page.

Comment: What are you expecting? You don't have a background color or anything in it to actually see it. Apply `background: blue`: https://jsfiddle.net/xgz1w0rc/ Note, there are three because `*` also takes into account both `html` and `body`. You can avoid those by doing `html *::before` etc...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xgz1w0rc/1/ chk this please .. i added a `wrap` class and i want this to be applied to everything in that class. `class` and `class1`

Comment: You need to do `.wrap *::before, .wrap *::after`, not `.wrap *:before, *::after`: https://jsfiddle.net/xgz1w0rc/2/

Comment: how could i miss that possibility.. Thanks a ton!!